# lights gameobjects does not have a light component?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a bit stuck with lights management.

I have 4 lights; each with a tag ""lights_hall". In my code, I do assign all these lights to a gameobject list

```
roomlights = Gameobject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("lights_hall");
```

I get the list with the gameobjects, which I assume they are lights.

Then I go through each element of the list, to turn them on and off, but I get an error when the script try to retrieve the component "Light".

```
    foreach (GameObject single_light in roomlights)
    {
        if (single_light.GetComponent<Light>().intensity == 1)
            single_light.SetActive(false);
        else
            single_light.SetActive(true);
    }
```

Unity tell me that there is no light component attached to the gameobject. How is this possible if the light component is part of a light gameobject?

I did check some examples and they all do the same: create a list of gameobjects, use find to get all the lights that has the tag as specified, and then access the light component for each element in the list.

Am I missing something here? I did also try to access each single element light component, so I can use .enable, but it does not appear in auto completion.

EDIT==================================

This is the script that I use; it is attached to a simple cube, which has a collider, so when the first person controller get in the trigger area, and you press "l" on the keyboard, the ligths should turn off.

I did verify the names, and the names are matching the point light game objects in the scene; although Unity print the error `"MissingComponentException: There is no "Light" attached to the "switch" game object, but a script is trying to access it. You probably need to add a Light to the game object "switch". Or your script needs to check if the component is attached before using it"`

The ligts are point lights; nothing out of the ordinary.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class LightsSwitch : MonoBehaviour {

    private bool istriggered = false;
    public GameObject[] roomlights;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        roomlights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("lights_hall");
        foreach (GameObject light in roomlights)
            Debug.Log(light.name);

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        if (istriggered && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.L))
        {

            foreach (GameObject single_light in roomlights)
            {
                if (single_light.GetComponent<Light>().intensity == 1)
                    single_light.SetActive(false);
                else
                    single_light.SetActive(true);
            }
        }

    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider world_item)
    {
        istriggered = true;
        Debug.Log("light switch");
    }

    void OnTriggerExit(Collider world_item)
    {
        istriggered = false;
        Debug.Log("light switch gone");

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't assume - confirm. Print out the name of each single_light gameObject as you iterate over it. The code you provided works (tested in a very basic scene) so that shouldn't be the cause of the issue.
I'm not sure what to infer from the `Behaviour.enabled` field not appearing on a light component, except that it might not be the light at all.

Comment: I may agree on your point; but if I have to verify every single thing in an API, to validate that the documentation is correct; then I may well take 10x the time needed to write a piece of code :) I will do that; so I can get more insight in my question.

Comment: Regarding the second part of your comment; if I have a GameObject; which in fact I do have (I did check the content of the array); it should have the .enable method. Instead I do not have it in the list of the methods in that object; which is why I am totally confused. a light is a gameobject with a light component on it; so independently from everything, it must have the transform (it does), and should have the enable method (which it does not have). Looking further in this issue.

Comment: Can you show more code? Perhaps your roomlights[] declaration. 
You're also saying single_light.GetComponent<Light>(), but then you disable the whole GameObject <single_light>, not doing single_light.GetComponent<Light>().SetActive(false);

What line does the console report as an error?

Comment: "Gameobject" is a syntax error, which you don't need StackOverflow to tell you; same with "enable". It's `enabled`, which is not a method (as you called it) but a property. You should know all this from reading Unity's console output. Light is the component, irrelevant to the gameobject; components have `Behaviour`. `Behaviour.enabled` is not a property on the `GameObject` component. Be very very clear on the distinction between the gameobject and the component, it might be related to the cause of your issue.

Comment: I did modify the question to add the whole script; the errors in the original post were typo; since I didn't copy and paste. I did try to access the light component, but pressing the dot again, won't give me the enabled. I could access the strenght, intensity and all the other parameters, but not the enabled.

Comment: Also make sure to add istriggered=false; onTriggerExit()

Comment: Yep, that's there already; it is the way that I use to enable and disable the switch activity (the button pressing is context based, so on a switch it turn off lights; on a door it opens it and so on).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few issues.

First, in your code:

```
roomlights = Gameobject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("lights_hall");
```

Make sure to change Gameobject to Game**O**bject.

Now, assuming roomlights is a GameObject[], set your code as follows:

```
foreach (GameObject single_light in roomlights)
    {
        if (single_light.GetComponent<Light>().enabled == true)
            single_light.SetActive (false);
        else
            single_light.SetActive (true);
    }
```

My suggestion would be to disable the Light component, rather than the whole GameObject  itself. This can be achieved with:

```
single_light.GetComponent<Light>().enabled = false;
```

### I've setup an example project, this implementation should work for you.

[image: Hierarchy setup and inspector]

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class turnofflight : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject[] roomlights;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        roomlights = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("light_comp");
        foreach (GameObject light in roomlights)
            Debug.Log(light.name);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        foreach (GameObject single_light in roomlights)
            {
            if ((single_light.GetComponent<Light>().intensity == 1.0f))
                    single_light.SetActive(false);
                else
                    single_light.SetActive(true);
            }

    }
}
```

I'm having no issues with this implementation.

Comment: Sorry for the typos; I did post the whole script to show what I do in it. I was not able to access the light component.enabled property at all; which is why I tried different ways to actually turn on and off the lights.

Comment: Are your GameObject's with tag "lights_hall" children of anything? Assuming the aforementioned roomlights GameObjects are being found during your FindGameObjectsWithTag, try outputting their single_light.name variable, or disabling them and check the inspector, and see if you're referencing the correct objects. Then double check that you do indeed have Light components attached to the roomlights GameObjects. 

What line is the error on?

Comment: Yes, they are child of another object, which is an architectural mix of elements; but has no scripts on it. Just meshes. The list contain the lights elements, I did print out the names and they are correct; also in the inspector, I can turn them on and off without problems, which is why this whole thing does not make sense to me. I will try to put the lights on their own in the root of the hierarchy and see if that matters. The error is coming from the line that check for the intensity; that's the one that complain that the script is trying to access the component that is not there.

Comment: See my edited answer and let me know what you're doing differently. Its working fine for me! Perhaps a screenshot of your Hierarchy would help?

Comment: Thanks; I see that my hierarchy was different from yours....it should not really matter but it seems it does. I did put all the lights in a game object and put it on the top of the hierarchy, and it is all fine now. Thanks for showing me the screenshot

Comment: @newbiez it does not matter, but you need to make sure you're correctly calling references to components if your hierarchy is setup a different way.